# How to get attribute value of next child in XML tree using ElementTree

Tags: python, xml-parsing, elementtree

I am parsing an XML file using ElementTree. But I don't know how I can access the next element while parsing. What I want to do is print a particular tag to a file, if the same tag corresponding to the next child is the same. Eg. If 5th element's `code` tag is 12345 and that of the 6th element is also 12345, then i want to print the code in a file.

Something like:

```
for child in root:
    if child.find('code').text == next(child).find('code').text:
        file.write(child.find('code').text + "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

this was tested and should work:

```
it = root.iter('code')
prev = it.next()
for current in it:
    if prev.text == current.text:
         print prev.text
    prev = current
```

you can also use `zip`:

```
for current, next in zip(codes, codes[1:]):
    print map(lambda node: node.find('code').text, [current, next])
```

Comment: I will be only getting the 'code' of the second child, and miss the first. E.g. if 3rd and 4th children have same 'code' then only the code of 4th child will be printed

Comment: add another way using zip